# Is it even possible to cut just the phloem from the stem of a plant?

Tags: botany, plant-anatomy

I often see questions related to this kind of diagram:

[image]

Basically, the diagram shows a that phloem is removed from the stem in the middle of the plant. Thus, the stem swells because food produced by the leaves cannot travel further. However, is it even possible to do this experiment in real life? Is it possible to cut just the phloem from the stem?

Comment: Why do you think it is not possible?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [ask] effective questions on this site. In particular, we expect users to demonstrate that they have done the expected prior research — search for 'homework' in the help section for details. I suggest you start with [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girdling). After that please either delete or [edit] your question to make it on-topic for this site. Thanks.

Comment: The phloem and xylem are tissues with reinforced tubes, they are stronger than the meristematic tissue between them. This sort of splitting happens easily.